# How to display parameter info for an overloaded constructor in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I know that Ctrl+P will display parameter info, but when a Java class has multiple constructors, it only display one constructor's parameter info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not reproducible for me.

In my case, the parameter info for all constructors in the class is displayed :

[image]

Also by using "[Super Method Completion](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/09/super-method-completion/)" it is possible to have the constructor args automatically populated by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> :

[image]

This feature should be present in Idea versions 10.5+ as documented [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/viewing-method-parameter-information.html).