# IntelliJ JavaDoc proposals like Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, javadoc

Hello I didn't know what to search for, if I did I wouldn't be here. 
In Eclipse when I write `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog` the JavaDoc shows up and when I press `showOptionDialog` this comes ups on screen (In the yellow thingy)

```
JOptionPane.showOptionaDialog((Component parentComponent, Object message, String title,         int optionType, int messageType, Icon icon, Object[] options, Object initialValue)
```

But when I type it in IntelliJ only `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog();`
shows up, and I am new to programming and I can't remember what I have to write when.

Is there any way I can get it to show in IntelliJ too?

Comment: See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358810/how-to-display-overloaded-constructor-info-in-intellij/19359178#19359178 (Specially the bit about super-method-completion)

Answer (score 1):

In IDEA you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to get the Parameter information of the current call.

And: that stays relevant, even when you're more experienced, as memorizing *every possible API* is not a useful way to spend your time ;-)

Comment: And use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to have the parameters automatically filled in (See [this](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/09/super-method-completion/))